# How to use isset condition in laravel controller

Tags: laravel

I want to check whether id value is zero or not using isset.But it shows an error Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

```
$id = isset($request->route('id'))?($request->route('id')):0;
```

Comment: $request return an objects

Comment: simply use the Null coalescing operator rather then isset().
$id = $request->route('id')?? 0;

Comment: not sure how checking for `0` and `isset` are related here

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are not checking for `0`, you just want `0` as a default value if the route parameter `id` doesn't have a value:

```
$id = $request->route('id', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may Use Like

```
    $idval = $request->route('id');
    $id = isset($idval) ? ($idval) : 0;
```

Because isset only works with variables and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$id = (isset($request->route('id')))?$request->route('id'):0;
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use the Null coalescing operator rather then isset().

```
$id = $request->route('id')?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define default value on the method arguments

`$id=0`

// rout sample
Route::get('/test/{id}', 'TestController@indexid');

```
// sample
class TestController extends Controller
{
  public function indexid(Request $request,$id=0) {
```